# Error creating db on Rails 6 with Postgres on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql

I have created an app on **Windows** using **Rails 6** and **sqlite3**. I have now deployed the app on **Heroku**, but I had to change the database to **Postgres**. Now that the change has taken place, I cannot create the new db for the rails project. It gives me the below error. I have checked various solutions on stack overflow, and found nothing.

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 3.0/pg_ext
Did you mean?  3.0.0/devkit
C:/Users/jpfer/OneDrive/Desktop/Projects/avondale_recruitment/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
C:/Users/jpfer/OneDrive/Desktop/Projects/avondale_recruitment/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg_ext
C:/Users/jpfer/OneDrive/Desktop/Projects/avondale_recruitment/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
C:/Users/jpfer/OneDrive/Desktop/Projects/avondale_recruitment/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

HAs anyone got any solutions please. I know running Rails and P{ostgres on Windows is a pain, but I am quite limited right now.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you also update your Gemfile & database.yml

Comment: Already done that.

Comment: Have you considered installing WSL and running Postgres (and eventually everything else) there?

Comment: I have now installed ubuntu and I am trying to run everything off that. I have managed to get everything done except postgres. I am now getting `connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory` when I run rails bd:create